# Handle retrofit 2 GSON conversion errors

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I am using retrofit with GSON and RxJava to carry out network requests. I am trying to figure out how to get the response when the Gson library fails to convert it.

This takes place when an error takes place on the server and the response does not match the class that the Gson library is trying to convert the response to.

A work around would be to create an interceptor and cache the response before we try to convert it. But that's just bad programming as the problem will become unmanageable once we start doing concurrent requests.

**the service is defined as follows: The response class contains just a status code and a generic type called data.**

```
Retrofit getService() {
     return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(url)
            .client(clientBuilder.build())
            .build();
}
public Observable<Response<String>> userLogin(String username, String password) {

    return getService().create(Account.class)
            .login(username, password)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

**Somewhere else in the code we create a request**

```
getService().userLogin(email, password)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(onSuccess(), onError());

protected Action1<Response<String>> onSuccess(){

    return new Action1<Response<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Response<String> response) {
             // Process the response
        }
    };
}
protected Action1<Throwable> onError(){
    return new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {

            if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                ResponseBody body = ((HttpException)  throwable).response().errorBody();
                // Handle the error
            }
        }
    };
```

The problem occurs when the server returns something other than a string. For example an object or an array. Here the GsonConverterFactory will throw an error that will be caught by the onError method. I am wondering how can I get response.

The throwable that is returned is of type `JsonSyntaxException` and sadly it does not contain the original response body that the GSON library has tried to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I suggested a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200023/log-response-body-in-case-of-exception/42203600#42203600) to a similar question, however you seem to need a slight modification of the answer. The answer also contain some comments on the efficiency and memory consumption concerns. If you'd use that solution, you could create a special failure handler that could create a special exception holding some failure information:

```java
final class BadPayloadExceptionConversionThrowableConsumer
        implements IConversionThrowableConsumer {

    private static final int MAX_STREAM_BUFFER_LENGTH = 8 * 1024;

    private static final IConversionThrowableConsumer badPayloadExceptionConversionThrowableConsumer = new BadPayloadExceptionConversionThrowableConsumer();

    private BadPayloadExceptionConversionThrowableConsumer() {
    }

    static IConversionThrowableConsumer getBadPayloadExceptionConversionThrowableConsumer() {
        return badPayloadExceptionConversionThrowableConsumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(final MediaType contentType, final long contentLength, final InputStream inputStream, final Throwable ex)
            throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(MAX_STREAM_BUFFER_LENGTH);
        copy(limit(inputStream, MAX_STREAM_BUFFER_LENGTH), byteArrayOutputStream);
        final ByteArrayInputStream bufferedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        throw new BadPayloadException(ex, contentType, contentLength, bufferedInputStream);
    }

    static final class BadPayloadException
            extends IOException {

        private final MediaType contentType;
        private final long contentLength;
        private final InputStream inputStream;

        private BadPayloadException(final Throwable cause, final MediaType contentType, final long contentLength, final InputStream inputStream) {
            super(null, cause);
            this.contentType = contentType;
            this.contentLength = contentLength;
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        MediaType getContentType() {
            return contentType;
        }

        long getContentLength() {
            return contentLength;
        }

        InputStream getInputStream() {
            return inputStream;
        }

    }

}
```

Rather than logging it only throws a special private-constructor exception that could be `instanceof`ed at the call site. The input stream must be buffered up to some limit for the reasons that are also commented in the related question (especially why a raw `InputStream` is delegated but not a `ResponseBody`). Now the way it can be used:

```java
service.getFooBar()
        .subscribe(
                out::println,
                t -> {
                    if ( t instanceof BadPayloadException ) {
                        try {
                            final BadPayloadException badPayloadException = (BadPayloadException) t;
                            err.println("Content type   = " + badPayloadException.getContentType());
                            err.println("Content length = " + badPayloadException.getContentLength());
                            err.print("Content        = ");
                            copy(badPayloadException.getInputStream(), err);
                        } catch ( final IOException ex ) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }
                    } else {
                        err.println(t.getClass());
                    }
                }
        );
```

Note that the `copy` and `limit` methods are static imports from Google Guava `ByteStreams`. `out` and `err` are static imports for `System.out` and `System.err` respectively.

Sample output:

```
Content type   = application/json
Content length = -1
Content        = ﻿{#"foo":1,"bar":2}
```